# microsoft report viewer 2015

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have installed a Microsoft Report Viewer 2015 runtime on a system I am developing and the first day it worked alright.  The following day it's giving type of namespace error Reporting. I checked the Reference folder and a yellowish triangle is now showing on the two files(Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms) listed there. I have tried reinstalling and to no avail. I need help folks, PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

You to pick your references from the

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer set of folders.

In each folder there is one for Common for example you will find 3 DLLS the latest is:

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll.

89845dcd8080cc91 is the Public Key Token.

Note if you are using the web forms version you need to add the following to your web config as the piblic key token is the same as for Report Viewer 11.

```
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```